# Grep log and get text between log delimiters

Tags: grep, subversion

Is there a way to `grep` a log and find text between the log entry delimeters?
Our log file separates the line entry with characters "`-------`"
So when I search the text word  I want all the lines before and after the delimeters in the log.

Sample log

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    r132279 | USERID | 2014-04-30 12:59:09 -0700 (Wed, 30 Apr 2014) | 3 lines
    Removed unused "Calculated Fields" column entry.
    Jira ID: JIRA-977

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above i would Grep the word Fields  but want all the lines between the "`----`" lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how big the record is, then you can output additional lines of context before (`-B`) and after (`-A`) the matching line e.g.

```
grep -A2 -B2 'Fields' sample.log
```

or for context both before and after the match line

```
grep -C3 'Fields' sample.log
```

As far as I know, the only way to do a true multiline match (rather than a single line match plus context) in GNU grep is by using the PCRE regex mode (`-P`) with the `-z` flag to prevent breaking on newlines. For example, you could try

```
grep -zPo '(\n-+\n)\K(.|\n)+?Fields(.|\n)+?(?=\n-+\n)'
```

which does a non-greedy match of the string `Fields` surrounded by any characters OR newlines, provided it is bookended by the *newline-hyphens-newline* delimiters. An equivalent expression in pcregrep is

```
pcregrep -Mo '(\n-+\n)\K(.|\n)+?Fields(.|\n)+?(?=\n-+\n)'
```

Another option for this kind of record-structured data is awk: in particular, GNU awk allows a regular expression to be used for the internal *record separator* RS e.g.

```
$ gawk -vRS='\n-+\n' '/Fields/ {print}' sample.log

r132279 | USERID | 2014-04-30 12:59:09 -0700 (Wed, 30 Apr 2014) | 3 lines

Removed unused "Calculated Fields" column entry.

Jira ID: JIRA-977
```

Comment: gawk worked well . But when there is no DESCRIPTION field it outputs all lines. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A Perl solution similar to the `gawk` one in [steeldriver's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129094/26909) in case `gawk` isn't available:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/= "-"x72 . "\n"} chomp and print if /Fields/' log_file
```

Replace 72 by the actual number of dashes in your delimiter.

Comment: Nice! I must make an effort to learn some perl - I was trying to figure out a way to do a multiline match with `grep -zP` but couldn't

Comment: @steeldriver I have seen people around here refer to a tool called `pcregrep` that is capable of doing multiline `grep`s.

Comment: Thanks, I have added tentative `grep -zP` and `pcregrep` solutions - feel free to improve them since I only know just about enough perl to be dangerous!